# java.util.concurrent.ScheduledExecutorService performance on different computers

Tags: java, timer, scheduledexecutorservice

I have 2 Java programs. Each has a memory region, and programs pass messages to each other's memory regions. Java program checks its memory region with ScheduledExecutorService at a certain period of time, i.e. 5 miliseconds. Then it does some conversion and prints the message to screen. Two programs run succesfully and they print messages to screen ( I have implemented all JNI related things and programs run succesfully). The problem is that when I start these programs on my computer (windows 8, 64 bits, 8gb ram, 2.67 Ghz i5 processor) they run really fast. However, when I run these **exactly** same programs with **exactly** same native c++ library where I handle shared memory related works, on a different computer they run **slower**. The more interesting is that I tried to run them on a both better computer with 32 gb ram, i7 processor and worse computer with 6 gb ram and 64 bits core duo cpu and still they run slower. So another computer with either better or worse features than my computer did not matter on the speed of programs. All I see they run slower on other computers.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Are you running on same version of JVMs and is it the Sun Vendor?

Comment: The precision of `sleep` in a JVM is only guaranteed to be about 15ms, if you need to sleep consistently for much less time you will have to busywait so that your `Thread` doesn't sometimes sleep for longer. Your loss in performance could be related to this.

Comment: @shazin My computer: 

java version "1.7.0_09"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_09-b05)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 23.5-b02, mixed mode). 

Other computer:

java version "1.7.0_40"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_09-b43)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 24.0-b56, mixed mode)

Comment: @BoristheSpider I corrected my question. It was saying 5 microseconds, I corrected it to 5 **miliseconds**. My current time interval is 5 ms. However when I increase it to 100 ms, then I see other machine's speed is almost same with mine. Interesting... Why does other machine work slower when interval is 5 ms. ??

Comment: @Carlos different CPU? Other programs running? The weather? These are hardware and JVM implementation issues - Java provides certain guarantees but the actual JVM could be accurate to one nanosecond if that was the implementation.

Comment: @BoristheSpider  You mean the actual Oracle JVM implementation gurantees accuracy of 1 nanoseconds. Can you please clarify your comment a little bit.

Comment: I said _could_. The JLS guarantees an accuracy of 15ms. The actual accuracy is that of the hardware and underlying impl - this is unknown.

Comment: Java 7 update 9 and update 40 were very different in terms of how they perform.  I suggest you try update 60 on both machines.  Sleeping for 5 ms will be about the same on each machine, it is what you do after you wake up and how long it take the code to warm up which will be different.

Comment: I had installed latest JDK1_0_8_05 on both machines. But id did not work. Same slowness on second machine.

Comment: Are you using same OS on all 3 nodes?

Comment: better computer is windows 8.1 same with mine. worse one is windows 7.